# Chrome: unable to get :focus CSS applied on anchors

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, accessibility

I'm trying without much success to apply some CSS for the :focus state on anchors

```
a:focus
{
    outline:1px black dotted;
}
```

Yes, that simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/b6dbuqqv/

But it doesn't work. (Windows 7, Chrome 36)

[image: Chrome: unable to get :focus CSS applied on anchors]

Apparently it seems to be something they implemented to get rid of the focus ring when focus is activated via mouse. Instead, with keyboard navigation it works as expected.

Is there a way to fix this behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that clicking on an anchor does not put the focus on the `<a>`. Consequently, the `:focus` pseudo-class doesn't apply. If you attach an `onfocus` event listener to the anchor, then you'll see that the event is not triggered on click (though navigating via the keyboard, tab/shift+tab works as expected): http://jsfiddle.net/b6dbuqqv/1/

A quick search on Chromium's bug tracker yields [crbug.com/388666](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388666), which reports that pressing the mouse key on an anchor does not focus it.

A work-around to the problem is to use the `:active` pseudo-class instead:

```
a:focus, a:active {
    outline: black dotted;
}
```

(and avoid unnecessary use of `!important`, by the way)

Comment: Yep, clicking on an anchor in Chrome only gives it the `:active` state but it only remains for as long as the mouse button is pressed. Seems like a JS solution will be needed.

Comment: anyway, could some -webkit- thingy exist to enable the normal functionality?

Comment: @ObiWanWesabi What do you mean by "normal functionality"? Getting a focus after clicking? Use `tabindex="0"`. Getting a style when the user pressed the anchor? Use `:active`. More background information can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Clicking_and_focus.

Comment: @WesleyCrushed Fixed the bug (available in Chrome 39).